# Is there a way to know if the map was successfully loaded? (in case of bad internet)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, leaflet, fluttermap

So I'm using the flutter_map package to include openstreetmap in my app. I want my app to skip the map if it can't load it within 10 seconds, in case the internet connection is too bad. Is there a way to know if the downloading process has finished?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on the `load` event on the map, it is fired when the map is loaded [load map event](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-load) or check if the TileLayer is loaded [load tile event](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tilelayer-load)

To check on the map `load` event you have to add the listener before you call `setView`

```
var map = L.map('map');
map.on('load', (e)=>console.log(e));
map.setView([0,0]);
```

Comment: OP is using Flutter, your answer is for JS.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but this might help future readers.

Probably the easiest way to do this is implement a custom `TileProvider`, following these instructions: https://docs.fleaflet.dev/plugins/making-a-plugin/creating-new-tile-providers. Then you can do whatever method of catching errors you wish inside of `getImage`, and set an external flag. Bit of a workaround, but the best way to do it.